# VS Creating Installer with SQL Server database in application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I am following a nice tutorial titled: Walkthrough: Adding a SQL Server Compact Database to an Application and Deploying it, from MSDN. Since this application will require SQL Server, .NET Framework and SQL Compact to be installed on the machine; I opted for the "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application" because I don't want to assume the user has internet connection. 
I went and downloaded the prerequisites software and saved them under:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages and placed them in the relevant folders e.g. .NETFramework under its folder etc etc (as suggested in the tutorial).

However! When I click publish now, Visual Studio 2012 Professional displays the following:

"Error 105 To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.exe' for item 'SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883. SQLCompactWalkthrough"

And I have already downloaded the prerequisite files and placed them under packages folder. What else could I possibly be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tumelo, make sure the prerequisite files you downloaded are indeed the .exe files and not the .msi files.

You can download the .exe files [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=17876)

Comment: Great! I struggled with the same issue for a while. Helped when I finally took the time to not speed read as I normally do.